# Why does collect(someThing) change the result of RETURN otherUnrelatedThing?

Tags: neo4j

I noticed some strange behavior that I don't quite understand. A user reported bug where they were missing posts.

After removing parts my full query at a time, I was able to isolate where the problem was.

This will return the correct posts:

```
  MATCH (author:User {user_id: { user_id })

  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author)

  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE NOT author.user_id = commentAuthor.user_id

  WITH
    post,
    author

  RETURN post  // returns the expected result
```

However part of the full query is to `collect(commentAuthor)`, so when I simply add that without even doing anything with it:

```
  MATCH (author:User {user_id: { user_id })

  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author)

  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE NOT author.user_id = commentAuthor.user_id

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    collect(commentAuthor) as commentAuthors  // because of this

  RETURN post  // becomes incorrect -  why would this change?
```

^ Causes some of the users more recent replied to posts to be thrown out.

---

**UPDATE**: So after learning that applying an aggregation can change the order, it so turned out that the post that I thought was missing just wasn't returned first, but towards the middle of the result, so I just had to ensure the order after the aggregation for the minimal query:

```
MATCH (author:User {user_id: { user_id })

  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author)

  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE NOT author.user_id = commentAuthor.user_id

  WITH
    post,
    comment,
    author,
    collect(commentAuthor) as commentAuthors

  RETURN post

  ORDER BY comment.createdAt DESC  // now gives me the expected result
```

This is a bit harder with the full query, however:

```
  MATCH (author:User {user_id: { user_id }})

  MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author)
  WHERE post.createdAt < { before } AND post.text =~ { keyword }

  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE NOT author.user_id = commentAuthor.user_id

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    max(comment.createdAt) as commentCreatedAt,
    count(comment) as commentsPerCommenter

  ORDER BY commentCreatedAt DESC  // I believe this happens too early.

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    sum(commentsPerCommenter) as commentsCount,
    collect(commentAuthor {.*, commentCreatedAt}) as commentAuthors

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentsCount,
    size(commentAuthors) as participantsCount,
    commentAuthors

  // I think some sort of ordering needs to happen here.
  // Before the UNWIND and after the collect(commentAuthor).

  // ORDER BY commentCreatedAt DESC here:
      // gives correct posts, incorrect participantsCount & commentsCount as 1-1

  UNWIND commentAuthors as commentAuthor

  RETURN collect(post {
    .*,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    commentsCount,
    participantsCount,
    notificationType: 'reply'
  })[0..{ LIMIT }] as posts
```

Ex. another attempt to order with `collect(commentAuthor)`:

```
  MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment:Comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor:User)
  WHERE NOT author.user_id = commentAuthor.user_id

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    max(comment.createdAt) as commentCreatedAt,
    count(comment) as commentsPerCommenter

  WITH
    post,
    author,
    sum(commentsPerCommenter) as commentsCount,
    commentCreatedAt,
    collect(commentAuthor {.*, commentCreatedAt}) as commentAuthors ORDER BY commentCreatedAt DESC
```

^ Both attempts give correct post order but incorrect counts.

In the end here is what I am trying to do:

```
---
Tom replied to 'your post'
1 hr ago  // based on time of Tom's latest comment in 'your post' (post.commentAuthor.commentCreatedAt)
3 participants | 3 comments
---
Erin replied to 'your other post'
2 hrs ago
5 participants | 6 comments
---
Kate replied to 'your post'
3 hrs ago
3 participants | 3 comments
---

* Tom may have also commented on 'your post' 1.5 hrs ago
but we only get the latest reply, which was 1 hr ago
```

Comment: Try using `RETURN DISTINCT post` to both queries, and let us know how they compare (only really necessary for the first query you're comparing...the second, with COLLECT(), already has distinct values because of the aggregation)

Comment: @InverseFalcon `RETURN DISTINCT post` doesn't seem to make a difference to either query.

Comment: Keep in mind the order may change when you add aggregations. I would expect the first query to have duplicate posts (that should be weeded out by using `RETURN DISTINCT` at the end of that query). What do the post counts look like for both queries when you're returning distinct posts?

Comment: 1st query without DISTINCT - 83 records,
1st query with DISTINCT - 8 records (but the correct result),
2nd query without DISTINCT - 8 records (but incorrect result),
2nd query with DISTINCT - 8 records (but incorrect result)


You are correct. I looked through the 2nd query results, and the post I expected to show up first was in the middle. Turns out the real problem is that in the full query, it doesn't seem to be ordering correctly by `commentCreatedAt DESC`.

Comment: Okay, so that makes sense. For the 2nd minimal query, it just needs an `ORDER BY comment.createdAt DESC` at the end to ensure order. For the full query however, it seems to need to be ordered before the `UNWIND`, but doing makes the counts 1-1 as we discovered in a previous question. :) Let me update my post with some findings, as I am unsure how to apply this to a more complicated query, basically having to `ORDER` right before the `UNWIND` I think.

Comment: @InverseFalcon While I understand that "Keep in mind that your aggregations only have meaning with respect to the non-aggregation columns, which act as grouping keys.", I don't see how else I would pass the `commentCreatedAt` through to `ORDER BY commentCreatedAt DESC` later.

Comment: Can you clarify the thing you're ordering? Is this the commentAuthors list in each post? Or the posts themselves? For each post, you have a collection of commentAuthors, each with their own commentCreatedAt, did you want to get the max commentCreatedAt for all commentAuthors and order your posts that way?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I want to order the posts themselves. Yes, each post has a collection of commentAuthor who commented in them, where the max commentCreatedAt is the time of the latest reply of that commentAuthor. Yes, I would like to order the posts by the max commentCreatedAt for each commentAuthor. This represents a list of your posts ordered by their latest reply time for each commenter i.e. like a notification of everyone who replied to one of your posts with most recent first.

Comment: @InverseFalcon I updated my question with a graphical representation, which should help clarify.

Comment: Ah, so you don't want commentAuthors collected per post, you want each commentAuthor on their own line, ordered by the latest commentCreatedAt for the commentAuthor on the post?

Comment: @InverseFalcon I believe we collected the commentAuthors per post so we can sum them to get the right commentsCount? I'm sorry, these words are confusing me, but if I can data that can resemble the GUI, then that's what I need. :) Let's try: "for each post that I've made, I want to see each person who has commented on it (but only their latest comment), and these posts replies would be ordered by the latest comment to that post from that commenter. so yes, this sounds like "each commentAuthor on their own line, ordered by the latest commentCreatedAt for the commentAuthor on the post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so with the clarified requirements, we want each commentAuthor on their own line per-post, with the number of participants and comments per post.

We're close, but we either need to calculate commentCount and participantsCount per post before we match to commentAuthors (probably by using pattern comprehension), or we can UNWIND our commentAuthors at the end and perform our ordering there.

Let's try the second approach, you were on the right track with using UNWIND anyway.

EDIT

We'll also LIMIT, and then COLLECT() the rows at the end, following your request in the comments.

```
MATCH (author:User {user_id: { user_id }})

MATCH (post:Post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(author)
WHERE post.createdAt < { before } AND post.text =~ { keyword }

// removing labels for now since the relationships should be enough
// to match to the right nodes
MATCH (post)-[:HAS_COMMENT]->(comment)<-[:AUTHOR]-(commentAuthor)
WHERE author <> commentAuthor

WITH
 post,
 author,
 commentAuthor,
 count(comment) as commentsPerCommenter,
 max(comment.createdAt) as commentCreatedAt

WITH
 post,
 author,
 sum(commentsPerCommenter) as commentsCount,
 collect(commentAuthor {.*, commentCreatedAt}) as commentAuthors

WITH
 post,
 author,
 commentsCount,
 size(commentAuthors) as participantsCount,
 commentAuthors

UNWIND commentAuthors as commentAuthor

WITH
 post,
 author,
 commentsCount,
 participantsCount,
 commentAuthor

ORDER BY commentAuthor.commentCreatedAt DESC
LIMIT 11 // adjust as needed

RETURN collect(post { .*, author, commentAuthor, commentsCount, participantsCount, notificationType: 'reply' }) as postReplies
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! In order to turn it back into a collection, nothing wrong with this, right?

UNWIND commentAuthors as commentAuthor

WITH
 post,
 author,
 commentsCount,
 participantsCount,
 commentAuthor

 ORDER BY commentAuthor.commentCreatedAt DESC

  RETURN collect(post {
    .*,
    author,
    commentAuthor,
    commentsCount,
    participantsCount,
    notificationType: 'reply'
  })[0..11]

Comment: Hmm, so in general, if I just want to get back a list of things, is it a better practice to return rows/records of things, instead of a single of collection of things? I've been doing the collection cause it returns an array []... which makes more sense to me / is easier to work with when it comes time to send to the client and render it with JavaScript.

Comment: I may have misspoken (deleted my last comment), this could work. Check it out and see if the results make sense. Though you may want to do your LIMIT after the final WITH, before you collect, rather than taking the slice of the collection

Comment: Yes, the results make sense. Thank you for always being my Neo4j savior. It really means a lot to me.  T^T

Comment: No problem! Definitely a non-trivial kind of query, glad we got it working for you. Updated the query to include your return with COLLECT(), though I used a LIMIT instead of getting a slice of the collection.